# REST pass multiple id's

Tags: rest

I mean the next situation 
`api/users` - get all users 
`api/users/5` - only user with id=5 
`api/users/1,2,7` - here we have `where_in('user_id', $ids);` select in our back-end
I do only one request to server passing list of ids and DB using one select - returns all information that I need.

**The main question: is it acceptable using REST this way?**

If we want to get users with ids 1, 2 ,7 do we need one request or three.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, I would probably treat the 1,2,7 as query parameters and add to the request as part of the query string:

```
api/users?query=1,2,7
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, because in REST, "**Individual** resources are identified in requests, for example using URIs in web-based REST systems." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). So by passing in a list, your are not accessing individual resources, but a set of resources. Therefore, I would say no.

Comment: That's not accurate. A valid resource can also be a collection of other resources. See https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm. 5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers